# Incorrect output when using floating

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math

#get base
inputOK = False
while not inputOK:
    base = input('Enter base:')
    if type(base) == type(1.0): inputOK = True
    else: print('Enter, Base must be a floating point number.')
```

> Enter base:1.0 Enter, Base must be a floating point number.

I can't get a correct answer when I input 1.0. It always output Base must be a floating point number. I want to get True and exit the loop. What's wrong with my program.

Comment: `input` returns `str` object, also use `isinstance(..., float)`

Comment: The result of type(base) == type(1.0) is True, I think is out of the loop, but why the program excute the else step?

Comment: it can't be `True` in given example

Comment: try `print(type(base))`

Comment: >>> base = 2.0
>>> type(base) == type(1.0)
True
>>> print(type(base))
<class 'float'>

I got the result as above, the base's type is float. It's True

Comment: you've obviously overwritten `base` object, try your example from scratch

Comment: yes, you are right.
I can overwrite the base object, and get a right answer. But I can't define it in my program and get a same answer. why is it?

Comment: read the first comment, after `input` `base` object has type `str`, not `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns `str` object so we need to convert to float manually,
- we use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) for type checking (if it needed).

Following [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) we can write

```
# get base
inputOK = False
while not inputOK:
    try:
        # user can pass 'inf', 'nan', no error will be raised
        # should we check this cases?
        base = float(input('Enter base:'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Base must be an integer or floating point number.')
    else:
        inputOK = True
```